# Getting a div to float left when inside another div

Tags: html, css, css-float

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BFjCE

I am trying to postion the div which is at the bottom of this example to the right of the larger div. They are both being floated left but the 2nd div won't postion next to the bigger one.

I am guessing it is something to do with the sizing and when ever i make it smaller it works.

This image shows what I mean

[image]

Comment: The larger one has a width of 60%, the smaller one has a width of 40%. This would be fine (and perfect) if you didn't have padding, but you do. You have to take padding into account as it makes elements wider, meaning they add up to over 100%, and so won't sit side by side. (You can test this by making 60% = 50% and it will fit)

Comment: The clue, my friend is in this line right here, written by you: *I am guessing it is something to do with the sizing and when ever i make it smaller it works.*

Comment: Of course!!!How stupid. Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have answered the question already, size of the `div` will matter. In case the adjacent divs size sum up more than the available width of the box containing them, it will cascade down. In case you still want them in same row, you would have to give `overflow-x`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the two widths in reality exceed the 100% page width, because you have padding on the widths. The padding is not included in the `60%` and `40%` widths that you specified for your sections, so the float is going past 100%, and thus the second element has been pushed down.

I did a quit edit to your CSS changing `.grid-1-2` from 60% to 50%, and this solved the problem.

```
.grid-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
}
```